# before_filter with another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, before-filter

I am trying to create an action that will check for every page if the user is logged in.
For that, in the controller `Home` I created this method:

```
def check_session
  if !session[:user_id]
    redirect_to :action=> 'login'
  end
end
```

And I've put this code at the head of the controller:

```
before_filter :check_session, :except => [:sub_layout, :authenticate, :login]
```

Now I want to use `check_session` from outside the pages of `Home`, lets say in the pages of `Users`. What is the correct syntax for calling a method of a different controller in the `before_filter`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you move everything you already have to the application_controller it will check for every controller in your app. Then use the [:skip_before_filter method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter) to bypass the check for whatever controllers/actions you want.

Comment: OK, and than how do I define the :except method?

Comment: Thank you! one other thing... Lets say I'll have multiple `before_filter`s, is there a way to specify which ones to skip?
Edit: I looked in the link for the method. It's explained over there... Thanks again!

Comment: I think you could use :skip_before_filter => [:check_session, :other_filter]

Comment: Actually the correct syntax was:
skip_before_filter :check_session, :except => [:index, :logout]

Comment: Right, but I was under the impression you were asking about skipping multiple *filters* not multiple *actions*